# setTextAppearance - not work for MaterialButton when try to disable click

Tags: android, material-design

Android 6.0

Android Studio 3.6

in my fragment when click button then I change style "on fly" like this:

```
  bluetoothPageViewModel.isDisableModeLiveData().observe(this, Observer {
      dataBinding.buttonStartSearchBluetooth.setTextAppearance(
          R.style.buttonDisableStyle
      );
  })
```

here xml layout:

```
 <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
     android:id="@+id/buttonStartSearchBluetooth"
     style="@style/buttonStyle"
     android:layout_width="0dp"
     android:layout_height="@dimen/button_height"
     android:layout_margin="@dimen/button_margin"
     android:onClick="onClickButtonStartSearch"
     android:text="@string/start_search"
     app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

and here styles.xml

```
<style name="buttonDisableStyle" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/default_button_textColor</item>
    <item name="backgroundTint">@color/button_bg_color</item>
    <item name="android:enabled">false</item>
    <item name="android:clickable">false</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/byttonTexAppearanceStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="byttonTexAppearanceStyle" parent="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Button">
    <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
</style>
```

But after call `setTextAppearance` I can still click button.
Why?

Comment: Because `setTextAppearance` changes the `TextAppearance`  and not the style. You have to call `setTextAppearance(R.style.byttonTexAppearanceStyle)`. To disable the button just use `button.setClickable(false)`

Answer (score 1):

`setTextAppearance` only take care about styling the Text of the View. Check the [official doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#TextAppearance) to see supported property that `setTextAppearance` affected.

You have to handle the other property manually, Check below:

```
bluetoothPageViewModel.isDisableModeLiveData().observe(this, Observer {
    dataBinding.buttonStartSearchBluetooth.setTextAppearance(
        R.style.byttonTexAppearanceStyle
    );

    dataBinding.buttonStartSearchBluetooth.setEnabled(false);
    dataBinding.buttonStartSearchBluetooth.setClickable(false);
    dataBinding.buttonStartSearchBluetooth.setBackgroundTintList(
        ContextCompat.getColorStateList(this, R.color.button_bg_color))
    );
})

<style name="byttonTexAppearanceStyle" parent="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Button">
    <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/default_button_textColor</item>
</style>
```